# Failed to setup loader in react-component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to setup a loader. But the code is never going through the if blocks.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import LoadingPage from './LoadingPage';
import { usersFetchData, addFollower, addFollowing, removeFollower, 
removeFollowing, resetUser} from '../actions/users';

class UserProfile extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
     this.state = {
        isFollowed: false,
        content: undefined
    } 
}

componentDidMount(){    
this.props.fetchData(`http://localhost:5000/api/user/
${this.props.match.params.uid}`);
    (Object.keys(this.props.user).length !== 0) &&
        (this.props.user.followers.includes(this.props.currentUser.uid)) &&
            this.setState({isFollowed: true});
}

openContentModal = (post) => {
    this.setState({content:post});
    console.log(this.state);
}

closeContentModal = () =>{
    this.setState(() => ({ content: undefined }));
    console.log(this.state);
}

render(){
        if (this.props.hasErrored) {
            return <p>Sorry! There was an error loading the items</p>;
        }
        if (this.props.isLoading) {
            console.log('loading...');
            return <LoadingPage />;
        }
        console.log(this.props.isLoading);
        return(
            <div className="userProfile">
                <div>
                    {console.log(this.props.user)}
                    { Object.keys(this.props.user).length !== 0 && 
                        <div className="user__details">
                            <div className="user__dp">
                                <div className="dp__container">
                                   <img src={this.props.user.avatar} alt= 
{this.props.user.name}/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="user__description">
                                <p className="user__name"> 
{this.props.user.name}</p>


                                <div className="user__button">
                                    {(this.props.currentUser.uid === 
this.props.user.uid) ?                  
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                   }

                </div>
                <div className="user__bio">
                   <p>{this.props.user.bio}</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    {/* <h3>Posts</h3> */}
                    <div className="userContent">
                    {this.props.user.posts && 
this.props.user.posts.map((post) =>{
                        return(
                            <div className="userPost">
                                <Link to= 
         {`/p/${this.props.user.name}/${post._id}`}>
        <img src={post.content}/></Link>
                            </div>                      
                        );
                    })
                    }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
}       
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
console.log(state.usersIsLoading); //getting undefined
 return{ 
     currentUser: state.auth,
     user: state.users,
     hasErrored: state.usersHasErrored,
     isLoading: state.usersIsLoading
 }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
return {
    fetchData: (url) => dispatch(usersFetchData(url))
};
};  

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UserProfile);
```

Action

```
export const userIsLoading = (bool) => ({
type: 'USER_IS_LOADING',
isLoading: bool
});

export const usersFetchDataSuccess = (users) => ({
type: 'USERS_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS',
users
});

export const usersFetchData = (url) => {
return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(userIsLoading(true));
    console.log('hi');
    axios
        .get(url)
        .then(res => {
            if(!res){
                throw Error(res.statusText)
            }
            dispatch(userIsLoading(false));
            console.log(res.data);
            return res.data;    
        })
        .then(users => {
            console.log('users',users);
            dispatch(usersFetchDataSuccess(users))
        })
        .catch(() => dispatch(userHasErrored(true)));
}
}
```

reducer

```
export const userIsLoading = (state = false, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case 'USER_IS_LOADING':{
        return action.isLoading;
    }   
    default:
        return state;
}
}

export const users = (state = {}, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case 'USERS_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS':{
        return action.users;
    }
```

i have consoled the state. then i am getting a valid boolean value from userIsLoading. But when i am consoling the state.userIsLoading, I am getting undefined. This is very peculiar.can anyone tell me where am i getting it wrong?

Comment: I don't know why you want to log in mapstatetoprops. I would spread all your state to props: const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    ...state
   }) Then in the render method you can console.log(this.props.userIsLoading). Have you tried that?

Comment: and if it's undefined, you probably did not dispatch the redux action which sets the state in redux? You can download redux devtools for chrome to inspect your redux state

Comment: We would need to see your redux reducers in order to help you.

Comment: please go through again. i have updated it @JonathanR

Comment: @charly1212 i have tried bot of your suggestion. Redux is also working fine.

Comment: First, just try logging `state` in `mapStateToProps` and share the output. Also please share your `combineReducers()` so that we can understand how your store keys/namespaces are organized. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky thanks mate. I just checked my combine reducer and found my error. It was typo error. It is 'userIsLoading', not 'usersIsLoading.

Comment: You may want to create an answer sharing your `combineReducers()` to possibly help others encountering a similar issue. Or if you share your `combineReducers()`, I'd be glad to make an answer. Thanks!